# How to create design time property in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

How do I make my own UserControl with design time properies? I want functionality like

```
<MyControl MyNormalProperty="..." d:MyDesignProperty="..."></MyControl>
```

I noticed that in Blend properties like that are used with `mc:Ignorable="d"` (to ignore them durning XAML loading at runtime) and `xmlns:d="some namespace"`, but I cannot figure out How to define such property in my code behind file for UserControl.

I could probably do AttachedProperty like this

```
<MyControl Whatever.MyDesignProperty="..."></MyControl>
```

But I was hoping for more uniform solution.

Thanks in advance